# How do I adjust the sensitivity of a PIR sensor

Tags: sensor, motion

I use a PIR sensor (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8630) with Arduino to detect people's presence. The sensor detects very well the movements directly in front of it, but it is less sensitive to motions that are more slender or that are further away.

How do I increase the sensitivity of such a sensor?

Answer (score 1):

Angle of detection of a PIR sensor is dictated by the shape and construction of its lens. There is no way to modify it in software or in the electronics.

Distance depends on the power of the IR source as well as the sensitivity of the IR sensor. This may be able to be tweaked, but the specifics will depend on the schematic as well as the components in use.

Answer (score 0):

That PIR module is a raw PIR sensor connected in a general purpose op-amp circuit, provided by a LM324 series quad operational amplifier. One way of increasing the sensitivity is by changing the value of a resistor or capacitor in one of the op-amp stages. This could lead to over-sensitivity, and false positives. It depends on what values are used.

The other method is by carefully positioning the sensor. PIR sensors are more sensitive to movement across it's field of vision, instead of head on movement. Someone walking straight towards the sensor will be less likely to trip it from far away than someone walking across it.

Aside from that, PIR sensors tend to be insensitive to slow or subtle movements, in general. It's just the nature of the technology. If you need more accuracy, you would want to use more sensors.